# Laravel: A unit test may not use the database

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, mocking, phpunit

Here is the code that I am trying to write unit test for:

```
$towpRepo = \App::make(TransportOrderWithoutPriceRepository::class);
$towp = $towpRepo->findByOrderNumber($orderNumber);
if ($towp) {
   $towp->delete();
}
```

Here is the `findByOrderNumber` method:

```
public function findByOrderNumber($orderNumber)
{
     return TransportOrderWithoutPrice::where('order_number', '=', $orderNumber)->first();
}
```

Now here is the test code:

```
$transportOrderWithoutPrice = mockery::mock('Phirater\Domain\TransportOrdersWithoutPrice\TransportOrderWithoutPrice');
$transportOrderWithoutPriceRepo = mockery::mock('Phirater\Domain\TransportOrdersWithoutPrice\TransportOrderWithoutPriceRepository');
$transportOrderWithoutPriceRepo->shouldReceive('findByOrderNumber')->once()->andReturn($transportOrderWithoutPrice);
```

Now whenever I run the test, it returns the following error:

PhiraterTest\Unit\Phirater\Domain\TransportOrders\CreateTransportOrderFromPriceResponseCommandHandlerTest::testCreateTransportOrder
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'What are you doing? A unit test may not use the database!' (SQL: select * from `transport_orders_without_price` where `order_number` = 1 limit 1)

```
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1719
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1704
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:481
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:465
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php:77
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/TransportOrdersWithoutPrice/TransportOrderWithoutPriceRepository.php:167
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/Configuration/Events/Listeners/CleanupTrait.php:59
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/Configuration/Events/Listeners/TransportOrderSubscriber.php:84
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:369
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:200
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:467
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Domain/TransportOrders/CreateTransportOrderFromPriceResponseCommandHandler.php:117
/home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/tests/unit/Phirater/TransportOrders/CreateTransportOrderFromPriceResponseCommandHandlerTest.php:90
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am on `laravel 5.5` and `phpunit 6.5.14`.

Comment: Can you show `phpunit.xml` and `config/database.php` please?

Comment: You can definitely use the database in a unit test (laravel)... that is very opinionated from that package... If you have a service that does specific calls to the database, you would have to use a factory to create the data, but you do a real call to the database, you NEVER mock the database... Here you have more info about [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#introduction)